# Can I use "Would" instead of the infinitive?

Tags: grammaticality, indirect-speech

In the example, "I expect she will not tell the truth/ I don't expect she will tell the truth," said the judge.

My teacher said that it should be reported this way, "The judge didn't expect her to tell the truth"

But can we report it by saying, "The judge didn't expect she would tell the truth"?

Comment: I’m not sure there’s any benefit to that change. However, the way to report it is to say: “The judge said that he didn’t expect her to tell the truth.” We know what the judge said, which is what should be reported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*"Would" is used after past reporting verbs where "*will*" was used in direct speech.* This is contained in *Practical English Usage* (Michael Swan, OUP 1995, n° 604, indirect speech). Therefore, the two formulations can be used for the same purpose.

> (PEU)
> direct:  *Tomorrow will be fine.*
> indirect: *The forecast said that the next day would be fine.*

reporting verbs: [resources for learning english](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/reporting-verbs/)